# As a group admin of telegram supergroup, how can I disable link previews

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Telegram by default enables [link previews](https://telegram.org/blog/link-preview) for messages. I have created a bot in python that monitors the group as Admin and verifies that there are no vulgar messages (by analyzing message text for certain slangs). Next I want to improve the bot so that it can disable/delete any messages which have link preview enabled. I have looked into [message object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) and there is no information which I can use to know if preview is enabled or disabled in a message posted on supergroup.

Has anyone encountered same issue and were you able to solve it?

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#editmessagetext has `disable_web_page_preview`.

Comment: thanks @AliHashemi, that method is however to disable web_page_preview for the message bot is sending to a group. I however want my bot to disable web_page_preview for any message sent by members in the group.